# On mouseleave executed before leaving the element: javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am trying to executing mouseenter() and mouseleave() in this code,

the problem is that the event mouseleave is executed quickly before leaving the element,

I am trying to figure out why this is happening?

```
function home(){
        $(".light").css("margin-left","440px");
        $(".isik").css("margin-left","385px");
        $(".isik").parent().attr("href","index.php");
    }
    function work(){
        $(".light").css("margin-left","760px");
        $(".isik").css("margin-left","705px");
        $(".isik").parent().attr("href","refereanslar.php");
    }
    function contactus(){
        $(".light").css("margin-left","910px");
        $(".isik").css("margin-left","855px");
        $(".isik").parent().attr("href","iletisim.php");
    }
    function aboutus(){
        $(".light").css("margin-left","600px");
        $(".isik").css("margin-left","550px");
        $(".isik").parent().attr("href","hakkimizda.php");
    }
    $(".contactus").mouseenter(function() {
        contactus();
    })
        .mouseleave(function() {
            home();
        });
    $(".work").mouseenter(function() {
        work();
    })
        .mouseleave(function() {
            home();
        });
    $(".aboutus").mouseenter(function() {
        aboutus();
    })
        .mouseleave(function() {
            home();
        });
```

you can see the complete code in the link associated,

http://filikaajans.com/test/index.php

Comment: checkout your markup inside #navlist inside ul direct children should be only li elements. Please validate your markup. also you can try hover() instead mouseleave and mouseenter if it solves problem

Comment: try
`$('.aboutus').hover(function() { 
   aboutus();
},function() {
 home(); 
});` like this and let me know the OP

Comment: thanks #Pravin Vacihal
I added other elements to the UL, because I want this elements to be styled, only some of the elements I want them to be styled while the others the normal style, can I style some of the lis I want them with -45 degree???

Comment: #CJ Ramki

I tried it but onleave doesn't work, because I am changing the css of an element I need it to reset it on leave

Answer (score 1):

The following is the problem:
when the mouseenter-event occurs and the two images, e.g.

```
$(".light").css("margin-left","760px");
$(".isik").css("margin-left","705px");
```

are placed OVER the actual hovered element, the mouse-leave event is triggered, because the mouse is now over the `.isik` image....
To prove what I am saying: just remove the `isik`image and it works...

Comment: thanks #Homungus
but I need the isik image, I can't do without it,
what do you suggest?

Comment: @MFH you have different possibilities. e.g. use a backgorund-image for the links instead of placing the image on top. Or position the element and use different `z-index`.